# In real life, how do we discourage banal appeals to authority?

Tags: discussion

Many of the questions listed in [Should we limit [quote] questions?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3192/should-we-limit-quote-questions) are questions examining a claim that X said Y which involve an appeal to the authority of person X.

However, I'm not wondering about skeptics.SE policy. I'd like to know how to discourage appeals to authority (or at least banal and irrelevant appeals to authority) in real life, outside of skeptics.SE.

I've heard of yourlogicalfallacyis.com (in particular https://yourlogicalfallacyis.com/appeal-to-authority ), but to me linking to a website like that is only useful when you're telling someone you don't like that they're wrong and to STFU. I'm more wondering about basically telling someone that I more or less agree with (or understand) their opinion about a topic, but sharing a "quote" by Einstein isn't the best approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sharing a quote by Einstein isn't an argument for a position; it is popularizing a (hopefully) correct proposition. That isn't an appeal to authority in a logical fallacy sense because it doesn't say "this proposition is correct *because* Einstein thinks so". It would be using the prominence of Einstein to promote a piece of knowledge.

Whether a quote by Einstein is an effective way of spreading knowledge is an empirical question that I don't know the research on.

When somebody makes an *inappropriate* appeal to authority, just ask for evidence instead, or assess the argument logically on its own merits, ignoring the authority.