# Where should quote-hunting questions go?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, quotes

Skeptics.SE regularly receives on-topic questions of the form *"[Did Person X say Quote Y?](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3192/should-we-limit-quote-questions)"*

The answers fall into a few categories:

- Yes, they said it at Event Z.
- No, Person A said it, at Event Z.
- There's no evidence Person X said it.

That last one has an obvious follow-up question: *"Who said Quote Y?"* or more precisely *"Has anyone of note ever asserted Quote Y?"* (as opposed to using it as a joke or aspersion).

Is this question on-topic here?

Comment: There's the nuance that perhaps not every quote is notable for challenge here. https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4333/11643 talks about this a bit. I may flesh it out more here later.

Comment: @fredsbend it sounds like you're implying "Yes, if the quote is notable enough".

Comment: Yes, if it's remarkable that someone would say something, I think that's usually notable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example question on the main site makes the answer here much clearer.

The sequence was:

- Q: Did Goebbels advocate that you should do *[unethical thing]* with this quote?
- A: No, Goebbel said the enemy did *[unethical thing]*. He did not advocate it.
- This meta question asking if quote-hunting is permitted.
- The [main site question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/45201/has-anyone-directly-advocated-accuse-your-enemy-of-what-you-are-doing) which asks whether *anyone* advocated doing *[unethical thing]*.

But, our scope - our *raison d'etre* - is to tackle widely-believed claims.

No-one has claimed that anyone else has advocated *[unethical thing]*, except Goebbels, and we already have a question about that. There is no claim here to support or debunk, so it is off-topic.

[Wikiquote](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Anonymous) seems like a better place for this sort of hunt than here.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.